# When i try to login to a created account iy doesnt recognise the username, why is this?

Tags: vb.net

```
Module Module1
    Dim database As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim ulist As New List(Of String)
    Dim plist As New List(Of String)
    Dim newname As String
    Dim passw As String
    Sub main()
        menu() '
    End Sub
    Sub menu()
        Console.WriteLine("type 1, 2 or 3")
        Console.WriteLine("1 : create a new account")
        Console.WriteLine("2: log in ")
        Console.WriteLine("3 : quit program")
        Dim choice As String
        choice = Console.ReadLine()
        If choice = "1" Then
            create()
        ElseIf choice = "2" Then
            login()
        ElseIf choice = "3" Then
            Console.WriteLine("quitting...")
            Console.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub login()
        Dim unamever As String
        Dim passwvari
        Dim veri3 As Boolean = False
        While veri3 = False
            Console.WriteLine("please enter you username")
            unamever = Console.ReadLine()
            If ulist.Contains(unamever) Then
                Console.WriteLine("please enter your password : ")
                passwvari = Console.ReadLine()
                If plist.Contains(passwvari) Then
                    Console.WriteLine("logging you in...")
                    veri3 = True
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("password incorrect try again")
                    veri3 = False
                End If
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("username not registered try again")
                veri3 = False
            End If
        End While



    End Sub
    Sub create()
        Dim veri As Boolean = False
        Dim attempts As Integer = 1
        Do Until veri = True
            Console.WriteLine("enter a new username")
            newname = Console.ReadLine()
            If ulist.Contains(newname) Then
                Console.WriteLine("that username is already taken, try again")
                attempts = attempts + 1
                veri = False
            Else
                ulist.Add(newname)
                Console.WriteLine("your new username has been stored")
                notused()
                veri = True
                database.Add(newname, passw)
                Console.WriteLine("succes you have made an account you username :" & newname & " and password: " & passw)
                FileOpen(1, "C:\Users\iivix\OneDrive\Documents\A LEVEL\passws.txt", OpenMode.Output)
                PrintLine(1, newname & passw)
            End If
            If attempts > 4 Then
                Console.WriteLine("you have had more than 3 tries, BYE")
                Console.Clear()
            End If
        Loop

    End Sub
    Sub notused()
        Dim veri2 As Boolean = False
        While veri2 = False
            Console.WriteLine("create a password " & newname)
            passw = Console.ReadLine
            Dim passwlen = Len(passw)
            If passwlen > 12 Then
                Console.WriteLine("your password has been stored ")
                plist.Add(passw)
                veri2 = True
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("try again password must be greater than 12 characters")
                veri2 = False
            End If


        End While


    End Sub

End Module
```

This code is for a login system, I am a vb beginner and this is my code so far I have come across a problem: why aren't the usernames being stored when I try to log in later, how can I fix this? I want the user to be able to log back into an account when it is created another problem when writing usernames and passwords to a text file the new username overwrites the last, I want the usernames to be consecutively listed along with passwords'

- BTW this isn't homework, its a beginners programming challenge

Comment: VBA, vb.net and VB6 are not the same things, please don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: As this looks like your homework, I will point you in the direction rather than give you an answer - 1. You are not loading the usernames/passwords from the file before checking. 2. When storing the usernames/passwords you are doing in a way to make it impossible to identify each part

Comment: Also be aware of character casing

Comment: It looks like any password in the text file is acceptable for any username. Don't you want the password that matches the username?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code to use .net methods rather than obsolete VB6 methods. I made the `LoginPath` a Module level variable so it can be seen my all the methods in the Module. I am using a `Dictionary` rather than your 2 `List(Of String)`s. This way the username is the key and the password in the value. Dictionary lookup is very fast.

The first thing to do is to read the file and and fill the dictionary. If the file doesn't yet exist the user is informed.

The Create method changes a bit with the use of the Dictionary. I used the .net `File` class to write to the text file.

```
File.AppendAllLines(LoginPath, {$"{newname},{passw}"})
```

This is a very clever method. If the file doesn't exist, it creates it. It opens the file writes to the file and closes it. The first parameter is the path. The second parameter is what to write to the file, a String array. Notice the method names ends with AllLines, plural. The outer braces indicate that this is an array. Our array has only one element. I used an interpolated string indicated by the `$` preceding the string. We can then insert variables directly into the string surrounded by braces. The comma is a literal in the string. We use the comma as a delimiter when the string is split into name and password.

```
Private LoginPath As String = "C:\Users\iivix\OneDrive\Documents\A LEVEL\passws.txt"
Private LoginDict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Sub Main()
    ReadLoginFileAndFillDictionary()
    menu()
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
Private Sub Menu() 'Names of Subs, Functions etc. should begin with capital letters
    Console.WriteLine("type 1, 2 or 3")
    Console.WriteLine("1 : create a new account")
    Console.WriteLine("2: log in ")
    Console.WriteLine("3 : quit program")
    Dim choice As String
    choice = Console.ReadLine()
    If choice = "1" Then
        Create()
    ElseIf choice = "2" Then
        Login()
    ElseIf choice = "3" Then
        Console.WriteLine("quitting...")
        Environment.Exit(0)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Create()
    Dim veri As Boolean 'Default value is False, value types initialize automatically
    Dim attempts As Integer
    Dim newname As String = ""
    Dim passw As String = ""
    Do Until veri = True
        Console.WriteLine("enter a new username")
        newname = Console.ReadLine()
        If LoginDict.ContainsKey(newname) Then 'Searches the Keys in the Dictionary and returns True or False
            Console.WriteLine("that username is already taken, try again")
            attempts += 1 'new syntax for updating the value of a variable, saves a bit of typing
        Else
            veri = True
        End If
        If attempts > 4 Then
            Console.WriteLine("you have had more than 3 tries, BYE")
            Console.Clear()
            Environment.Exit(0) 'To end the application
        End If
    Loop
    veri = False 'You can use the same variable just reset its value
    While veri = False
        Console.WriteLine("create a password " & newname)
        passw = Console.ReadLine
        Dim passwlen = passw.Length 'Don't use the old VB6 Len
        If passwlen > 12 Then
            LoginDict.Add(newname, passw) 'Here is where the new user is added to the Dictionary
            veri = True
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("try again, password must be greater than 12 characters")
        End If
    End While
    Console.WriteLine("your new username and password have been stored")
    Console.WriteLine("succes, you have made an account your username :" & newname & " and password: " & passw)
    File.AppendAllLines(LoginPath, {$"{newname},{passw}"}) 'Adds the new user to the text file
End Sub

Private Sub Login()
    Dim unamever As String = ""
    Dim passwvari As String = ""
    Dim veri As Boolean 'You don't need a different name for a variable in a another method.
    While veri = False
        Console.WriteLine("please enter you username")
        unamever = Console.ReadLine()
        If LoginDict.ContainsKey(unamever) Then 'Searches the Keys in the Dictionary and returns True or False
            passwvari = LoginDict(unamever) 'Gets the value associated with the username
            Console.WriteLine("please enter your password : ")
            If passwvari = Console.ReadLine Then 'Compares the value found in the Dictionary to the string entered by the user.
                Console.WriteLine("logging you in...")
                veri = True
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("password incorrect, try again")
            End If
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("username not registered, try again")
        End If
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub ReadLoginFileAndFillDictionary()
    If File.Exists(LoginPath) Then
        Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(LoginPath) 'Read the file into an array of lines
        For Each line In lines
            Dim splits = line.Split(","c) 'Split each line by the comma into an array of 2 strings
            LoginDict.Add(splits(0), splits(1)) 'The first element is the username and the second element is the password.
        Next
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("There are currently no registered users. Please begin with Option 1.")
    End If
End Sub
```

In a real application you would **NEVER** store passwords as plain text.

Comment: file isn't declared

Comment: @kylegreene234 Add `Imports System.IO` at the top of the code file. That is where the File class is found.